# How to use enum as value of the dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dictionary, enums

Is there any way to do next, see example:

I have enum with Filters:

```
enum SearchFilters
{   
      Id,
      ItemsPerPage
};

enum ReportFilters
{
     Name,
     Age
};
```

And enum with pages:

```
enum Pages
{
     Search,
     Report
};
```

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, enum> filters = new Dicionary<string, enum>()
{
   {Pages.Search.ToString(), SearchFilters},
   {Pages.Report.ToString(), ReportFilters}
};
```

And use it like:

```
filters[Pages.Search.ToString()].  <--- and here will appear the list of enum values.
```

For example you can use a value of SearchFilters enum:

```
filters[Pages.Search.ToString()].ItemPerPage
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Better to use linq context for sucha this.

Comment: Your question is still ambigous for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. But I don't think the idea of having different enums in the same dictionary is good.

```
Dictionary<Pages, Type> filters = new Dictionary<Pages, Type>()
{
    {Pages.Search, typeof(SearchFilters)},
    {Pages.Report, typeof(ReportFilters)}
};

var arr = Enum.GetValues (filters [Pages.Report]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to either use
`Dictionary<string, Array>` :

```
var filters = new Dictionary<string, Array>()
    {
        { "Search", Enum.GetValues(typeof(SearchFilters)) }
    };

filters["Search"].Length; // 2. 
filters["Search"].Cast<SearchFilters>().Count(); // 2
```

or just store `Type` in `Dictionary<string, Type>`:

```
    var filters = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
    {
        { "Search", typeof(SearchFilters) }
    };

Enum.GetValues(filters["Search"]).Length; // 2
```

Comment: but the best way is to create your own class for that

Answer (score 0):

You cannot keep two different types in one dictionary (except you box-unbox the type). I'd suggest to keep the `Key` as `enum Page` and value as `List<string>`.

Then you can create following extension for enum:

```
public static List<string> ToMemberList(this Enum enumerationValue)
        {
            var type = enumerationValue.GetType();
            return Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
        }
```

And use it this way to create your dictionary:

```
var dit = new Dictionary<Pages, List<string>>()
                              {
                                  { Pages.Search, SearchFilters.Id.ToMemberList() },
                                  { Pages.Report, ReportFilters.Age.ToMemberList() }
                              };

var x1 = dit[Pages.Search];
```

Here x1 contains list of values in SearchFilters as string.

Note: Remember to keep the extension method inside a static class.